# Probability that at least one of three exam tickets randomly selected will be hard, if student considers 5 tickets out of 20 difficult.

Tags: probability

My interpretation: $$A \text{ - an event, that the ticket is difficult}\\ B \text{ - an event, that the ticket is easy}, n \text{ - the amount of tickets, } m \text{ - the amount of difficult tickets selected } \\ P_{3}(m \ge 1)= C_{3}^{1}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^1\cdot\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}+C_{3}^2 \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{1}+C_{3}^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{0}= \\ 3\left(\frac{9}{64}+\frac{3}{64}  \right)+\frac{1}{64}= \frac{37}{64}$$

First, I think it's incorrect, because the probability that the ticket is difficult is not constant, also because the probability to have at least one difficult questions is greater than one half, don't seem likely.

$$P(\text{ "probability that the first pulled ticket is difficult"})=\frac{5}{20}=\frac{1}{4} \\ P(\text{"probability that second ticket is difficult"})=\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{19}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{4}{19}  \\ P(\text{ "probability that the third ticket is difficult"})=\frac{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5}{4 \cdot 19 \cdot 18}+\frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{4 \cdot 19 \cdot 18}=\frac{29}{4 \cdot 6 \cdot 19}$$

Here it's weird, that no matter whether the difficult ticket is pulled or not the probability that the next ticket is difficult is much smaller, so I assume that the probability I am calculating is not the one I need to. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for correct approach: try finding the probability of the complement event (none of the three tickets are difficult).

> The probability that the first ticket is not difficult is $15/20$. Given that event, the probability that the second ticket is not difficult is $14/19$. Given all this, the probability that the third ticket is not difficult is $13/18$. Multiply them together and subtract the result from $1$.

---

Error in your first approach: this would be the correct approach if the tickets are drawn with replacement (i.e. it is possible to get the same ticket multiple times).

Error in your second approach: the probability that the second ticket is difficult is also $1/4$ (your computation is correct and your expression equals $1/4$, but this approach is unnecessary). The probability that the third ticket is difficult is also $1/4$. Here your computation is incorrect because you forgot some cases... there should be $4$ different cases for the different configurations of the first two tickets. But again this computation is unnecessary; the probability of any individual ticket being difficult is $1/4$. However, computing all these probabilities will not really help you answer the question of finding the probability that at least one is difficult.

Comment: Ok, but would it also be possible to write this probability as $P(A)=3\frac{5(15\cdot 14 + 15 \cdot 4 + 4 \cdot 3)}{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18}$ Or does this expression excludes some instances?